# What is the equivalent for LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, syntax, locking

I have a script that was generated in SQL Server 2008, but I need to execute it against a SQL Server 2005 database.

What would an equivalent statement for the following be in SQL Server 2005?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Event SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE` is the default behavior in SQL Server 2008 & is the ONLY behaviour in SQL Server 2005.

You can safely drop the statement without any change in functionality.

Answer (score 6):

There is no equivalent option: it's [new in SQL Server 2008](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/SQL-Server-2008-Partition-level-lock-escalation-details-and-examples.aspx).

You'll need to change the "Script For version" to SQL Server 2005,

Answer (score 2):

> <sup>[@gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27535/gbn) [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/843059/692942)</sup>
>   "*You'll need to change the "Script For version" to SQL Server 2005"*

In SQL Server Management Studio 2008 select menu Tools-Options ([SQL Server Object Explorer/Scripting Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326600.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

In the script generation wizard set the option Script For version to SQL 2005 that should give you the right script.