# SQL Server 2005 - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I generated in SQL Server Management Studio 2014 this automatic update script (after visual table editing):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

COMMIT

BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Rilevamenti ADD
    DataScadenza datetime NULL
GO

DECLARE @v sql_variant 
SET @v = N'Data di scadenza rilevata.'

EXECUTE sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', @v, N'SCHEMA', N'dbo', N'TABLE', N'Rilevamenti', N'COLUMN', N'DataScadenza'
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Rilevamenti SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO

COMMIT

SELECT
    Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.Rilevamenti', 'Object', 'ALTER') as ALT_Per, 
    Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.Rilevamenti', 'Object', 'VIEW DEFINITION') as View_def_Per, 
    Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.Rilevamenti', 'Object', 'CONTROL') as Contr_Per
```

Now I want to run the script on another database running on a SQL Server 2005 instance but when I run it I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'

Where is the syntax error?

Comment: I believe that "SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF" and "SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON" doesn't exists on SQL Server 2005

Comment: some of these commands don't exist it is a different version

Answer (score 3):

This is what happens when you generate a script inside a later version of SSMS *(SQL Server Management Studio)* then you're targeting with the script.

> <sup>[Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135850/sql-server-2005-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-set/36136077#comment59910250_36135850) by [@axmim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4625305/axmim)</sup>
>   *I believe that `SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF` and `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON` doesn't exists on SQL Server 2005*

<strike>Is absolutely right [`SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188791.aspx) wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2008.</strike>

---

**Update:** Was wrong [`SET SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188791(v=sql.90).aspx) is available in SQL Server 2005 *(even though the [first link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188791.aspx) says it applies to SQL Server (starting with 2008))* it looks like the `SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)` is the cause this wasn't introduced [until SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/a/843106/692942).

---

If you are going to generate scripts using the in-built `Generate Scripts` task in SSMS always remember to set the `Script for Server Version` on the `Advanced Scripting Options` dialog to the correct version of SQL Server you wish to target with the script.

[image: Advanced Scripting Options]

That way the script generated will be suitable for the version of SQL Server being targeted.

Comment: Oh interesting. But although I followed your tip (setted the Script for Server Version option on SQL Server 2005) the problem remains. Of course I've generated the script from scratch. Indeed the SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT instruction appears again in the script. And yes, @AXMIM, you are right, this SET doesn't exist for SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @jacktric That's strange it usually works for me, did it add `SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT` back in?

Comment: Maybe that's important: in the database options I see as database compatibility level SQL Server 2008 (100). And I'm not able to set this value on SQL Server 2005 (90).

Comment: @jacktric That probably won't help.